# Hybrid App platform & technology

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm a full stack developer with PHP, HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, Jquery, Angular and with enthusiast to lear any new technology.
Now i got a hybrid mobile app project(simpler with few curd operations and web services) and plus it will be web app as well, which i need to deliver as soon as possible. So my question is to choosing the right tool for the right job.
Hybrid App can be build with

- Platform: Phonegap or cordova, where cordova is extension of phonegap as per my
  understanding.
- Technologies: Plain html/css/jquery mobile or using
  some of the framework like ionic with angular.

So i want to know which tools and technology for building a hybrid app are preferable good and easy to learn faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually in traineeship and I just learn Hybrid apps in like 1 week and i'm only in my second year of computer science degree so I guess that won't be hard for you.

First of all, if you want a "light" and complete solution you can use [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). Documentation is good and you have a bunch of easy understandable exemple.

If I have to leave a malus, I encountered some installation problems.

You can also check [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) which is really fast to take in charge ( I did a 100% hybrid app with that in 2 days with both interactions ).

I didn't try it yet but I also heard positive things about [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) but I can't really help you there.

Hope that help you :)

Comment: will cordova supports for ios/windows, because i'm seeing that for ios it is very less support

Comment: It seems like Cordova support all OS, even Blackberry, Amazon etc.
I personnally only used Android so I can't help you on that :/

Answer (score 0):

if you dont know AngularJS the best way is trying [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).

[Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) is really awesome but you need skills in AngularJS.

Comment: yes i'm fine with angularJS, and thinking to go with ionic + cordova for the future projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to the Hybrid application, then use the [INTEL XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk) for developing your application. Download the SDK and create a new project and you can edit the index.html page in the www folder. After completing the coding, you can build your android/ios/windows/chrome/web application by selecting the build tab and provide certificates and build with just click start building. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can build Hybrid mobile apps using a phonegap,Cordova,IBM mobilefirst, IONIc.

I prefer IONIc. This is real good and amazing.
Everything is built in, including UI,Plugins to access native functions.

You can use IONIC 2 and Angular 2.

Comment: Its more than 2 year from time question was asked. I'm very well into react-native & IONIC doesn't give a good ux :)